# executing jQuery function after ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm using this [tagmanager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager) in my web application. The jQuery function works FINE until this

```
<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager" />
```

Is placed under

```
ng-repeat = "(key,val) in client_proj"
```

Here is a short snippet of the code

```
<div class="accordion-group" ng-repeat="(key,val) in client_proj"><!--For Every Project in Project List-->
  <div class="accordion-heading" style="background-color:#EFF8FB">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainAccordion" href="#{{val.id}}" ng-click="disableEditor()">
      <div align="center">{{val.title}}</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="{{val.id}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
    <div class="accordion-inner" style="font-size:12px; background-color:white">
      <strong>Technologies Exposure:</strong><br/>
      <div ng-hide="editorEnabled">{{val.exposure}}</div>
      <div ng-show="editorEnabled">
        <textarea ng-show="editorEnabled" class="span12" ng-model="val.exposure" rows="12" style="resize:vertical"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager" />
```

It appears as a normal input without doing any of its functions like creating a new tag after pressing, or enter.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Comment: I assume it's because the content of ng-repeat is not present when the  jQuery plugin runs. My suggestion is that you use a custom directive. I feel like anytime you need to write specific scaffolding html/css a directive is better suited. You have better control over rendering + behaviour

Comment: does it mean that i can't use the jquery tagmanager but instead have to create my own? im confused.

Comment: initialize the jQuery plugin from within the suggested directive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.Create a custom directive that acts as a wrapper for your jQuery plugin:

```
angular.module('<YOUR APP OR MODULE>').directive('tagsManager', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.tagsManager();
            //whatever other logic would go here
        }
    };
});
```

Then remove the automatic initialization of tabsManager (something like `$('<SELECTOR>').tagsManager();` or `jQuery('<SELECTOR>').tagsManager();` ) from your script

Ultimately, in your ng-repeat, add the directive to the input element (optionally add other attributes -- you might have to program the behavior for these attributes within your directive -- if they are required)

```
<input tags-manager>
```

This will make AngularJS initialize tabsManager on your inputs (via the custom directive) after they are rendered in the DOM.

Makes sense?

Comment: Hty! i think im starting to get an idea of what you are referring to. let me try it out and get back to u whether it is successful. Thanks alot mate!

Comment: Make sure to include scripts in this order: jQuery, jQuery plugins, angular.js, app.js, <controllers, services, directives, filters>...

Comment: hey thanks alot! it work like a charm and there's no need for me to further program the behavior for the attributes. THANKS! =D

Comment: Cool. If you do run into situations where you're trying to integrate something more complex into angular, then the directive code is the one you'll want to expand on.

Comment: yea! the ability to create directive for html is really powerful. just one last question, is it possible to dynamically update values in a custom directive? cause i realize that for the tags manager, i might need to call data dynamically to preload them into
element.tagsManager({
                prefilled: [dynamic data]

Comment: You could use ng-model or custom attributes that point to scope objects containing the data to create two-way bindings. Can't sum it up here, but read on http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive